# When is $f^{-1}(S^c)\neq \left(f^{-1}(S)\right)^c$?

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

Usually I apply the rule $f^{-1}(S^c)= \left(f^{-1}(S)\right)^c$ intuitively without thinking much about it. (the superscript $c$ denotes the complement-operation) However, I am not sure if this equality is wrong in some circumstances.

Let be $X$ and $Y$ two normed spaces and consider $f:M\to Y$ where $M\subseteq X$ and $S\subseteq Y$. By definition of the preimage we have $f^{-1}(S^c):=\{x\in M\mid f(x)\in S\}$. The complement of $f^{-1}(S)$, namely $\left(f^{-1}(S)\right)^c$ simply consists of all elements which are not in $f^{-1}(S)$. Consequently, this also includes elements of $X$ which are not included in $M$. So the equality  $f^{-1}(S^c)= \left(f^{-1}(S)\right)^c$ would be false.

Is this reasoning correct?

I am a bit confused because almost all functions in our course are defined like this: $f:M\to Y$ where $M\subseteq X$, meaning that the domain $M$ of $f$ is embedded in some normed space. Follwoing my above logic I wouldn't be allowed to apply this equality at all. Yet our professor uses the above equality!?

Am I missing something? Maybe someone can help to solve this confusion :)

Comment: That's why for a subset $A \subset X$, the notation $A^c$ is really bad. You should rather use $X \setminus A$ to always precise w.r.t. which set you are taking the complement.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe, so in this setting the equality $f^{-1}(S^c)= \left(f^{-1}(S)\right)^c$ is wrong and should be changed to $f^{-1}(S^c)= \left(f^{-1}(S)\right)^c\cap M$, right?

Comment: I would not say that it is wrong, but that the notation is too imprecise to understand if it true or not. What *is* correct is that $f^{-1}(Y \setminus S) = M \setminus (f^{-1}(S))$, and writing like this, there is no ambiguity.

Comment: In general, the complement of a set is not well-defined. You duality is true if $f^{-1}(S)^c$ is taken as the complement in the domain of $f.$

Comment: o.k. thanks I will keep this in mind when woking with complement operation.